# eclipse preferences: setting proxy bypass defaults via plugin

Tags: eclipse, preferences

i'm trying to set some values into the `Eclipse` preferences, especially in the network connections -> Proxy bypass. I want to make some own entries.
So how can I put there some values?
By the

```
IPreferenceStore store = JavaPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
```

or better by

```
InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode(...   ?
```

How do i access it, to put some values into?
Any hints would be welcome.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find details about `ConfigurationScope`, `InstanceScope` and `DefaultScope` [right here, from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html).

What you want to do is create `FieldEditor`s.

Create preference pages like this: 
`public class ProxyPreferencesPage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage`

You will also need a "static" class (preferably interface) to hold the preference keys
`IProxyPreferenceKeys` -> put all your preference variables here.

When you create the field editors, pass the preference constant to it.

```
new ColorFieldEditor(IProxyPreferenceKeys.PROXY, "Proxy color:", parent);
```

Finally, in your code, when you need the preference setting, just get it like this:

`Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getString(IProxyPreferenceKeys.PROXY)`

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for your advice. 
But i don't want to start a new page in the eclipse preferences, i wanna add values to the existing Proxy bypass field (on the network connection page).
your last code snippet is what i'm looking for, but I need more infomation about how to add the values into the store.
Or can I get access to the ProxyPreferencePage to add my values?

Comment: @Ahpuch Try using the `put` API from the `InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode(..)`, or the `setValue(..)` API from the preference store. Test it out. I think playing with the `InstanceScope` is the better solution, only you have to know the preference key of the proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

The Network Connections preference page is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.net.ProxyPreferencePage`. This does not get the values directly from preferences but via classes such as `ProxySelector` and `ProxyManager` (all internal classes).

Looks like the values actually come from `ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.core.net")` with the keys defined in `org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager`